# Sort an array of arrays by different indexes in C

Tags: c

Say I have a set of data points that are represented as an array of arrays of doubles, so

```
double **data;
```

Now if I wanted to sort the data by the some field in each of the data points, say the 2<sup>nd</sup> field, I would write a comparator that would do something like:

```
int compare_data_second_field(void *a, void *b) {
    double da = ((double *) a)[1];
    double db = ((double *) b)[1];
    if (da < db) return -1;
    else if (da > db) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

and then use `qsort` to sort them by the 2<sup>nd</sup> field.

My question is how do I generalize this if I don't know before hand which field I want to sort by? Like I may want to sort by the 1<sup>st</sup> field sometimes and the 5<sup>th</sup> field sometimes, etc. I would also like it to be thread safe so I don't want to use a global variable to keep track of what field to sort by since multiple of these might be going at once.

In C++ I would just use a custom sorting class and have an instance variable in the class to keep track of what field to sort by. I don't know how to do something like this in C.

Comment: You're actually grabbing the _third_ item. Are you aware of this?

Comment: Actually is `double **data;` not `double data**;`

Comment: Edited for both of these. While they are true, they are totally irrelevant to the discussion and don't really add anything, but whatever.

Comment: @pjreddie What platform are you working on? Are you using GCC?

Comment: Yeah, using gcc. I'd like this to not depend on compiler specific stuff but I guess qsort_r or nested functions might be the way to go, just to get it working right now. It's just a personal project so not that big of deal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way would be to use [`qsort_r`](http://www.ipnom.com/FreeBSD-Man-Pages/qsort_r.3.html) if it is available on your platform. [`qsort_r`](http://www.ipnom.com/FreeBSD-Man-Pages/qsort_r.3.html) accepts an additional argument that is passed to your comparator, so you could use that to pass the field by which you want to sort your data.

If that is not available on your platform, then there really isn't a simple way to do this. You can work around it using global variables, wrapping your data in a struct that would contain information on the sorting field, or rolling your own `qsort_r`-like function.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there's a pretty neat solution for this with *nested functions* (which are a GCC extension).
What you can do is make a generic comparator:

```
int my_comparator(const void* a, const void* b, int n)
{
    double da = ((double*)a)[n];
    double db = ((double*)b)[n];
    return (da > db) ? 1 : ((da < db) ? -1 : 0);  /* Awesome */
}
```

and a custom sorting function that wraps the original `qsort()`:

```
void my_qsort(void* base, size_t num, size_t size,
    int (*comparator)(const void *, const void *, int), int field)
{
    /* Internal comperator */
    int my_qsort_comperator(const void* a, const void* b)
    {
        return comparator(a, b, field);
    }

    /* Invoke the base qsort function */
    qsort(base, num, size, my_qsort_comperator);
}
```

This function behaves just like the original `qsort()`, except it takes an additional argument `field`, which indicates the index of the field to sort by.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a whole bunch of `compare_data_field_N` functions for N = 0,1,2... and then declare a `compare_data` array of function pointers initialized with the corresponding functions.  Then, to `qsort` on a specific field, you pull the function pointer from the array to pass to qsort.  You can use macros to make the generation of the functions and array simpler:

```
#define REP10(M) M(0) M(1) M(2) M(3) M(4) M(5) M(6) M(7) M(8) M(9)
#define DECLARE_COMPARE(N)                                         \
    int compare_data_field_##N(void *a, void *b) {                 \
        double da = ((double *) a)[N];                             \
        double db = ((double *) b)[N];                             \
        if (da < db) return -1;                                    \
        else if (da > db) return 1;                                \
        return 0;                                                  \
    }
#define REF_COMPARE(N) compare_data_field_##N,

REP10(DECLARE_COMPARE)
int (*compare_data_field[])(void *, void *) = { REP10(REF_COMPARE) };
```

You need only modify the REP10 macro if you want more than 10 potential fields.

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but I think the OP wants choose the index of the field to sort by at _run-time_.

Comment: Wow, this is compile time only, but nice preprocessor technique anyway :)